# Detecting subject in images

Tags: php, image-processing

I know there are some pretty impressive detection engines out there, which will let you input an image, and out comes whatever is the "main subject" in the image.

Lets say you give it a picture of a football, and it will return the text "football".

However I dont recall what these engines are called, and I just wonder if anyone has any pointers or names for good detection engines I can use with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Object detection algorithms? Maybe you could start of with something like [Face Detection with PHP](http://www.xarg.org/2008/07/face-detection-with-php/), but that ofcourse depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

i stumbled across something like this lately here, but no code or service for now. http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/deepimagesent/  or here http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4555